# How to create a widget in angular2 that communicate with another angular2 widget in one React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I have a parent application that can be in any front end technology stack like angular, angular2, ember, knockout.

For example;

My app is running in react-redux. I created a two different widget says widget1 and widget2 using angular 2. The idea is integrate this two widgets in  two different component in same page.

[image: Communication Between Two Angular 2 Widgets In React App]

R -> React App, A2 -> Angular 2. C -> Communication. (Seperate Widgets).

Like If i click add, 'll hit the service and update the another widget.

So, I can't fire action targeting widget1 from widget 2. Because, the parent app is "react-redux" app.

How can I make those two widgets interact with each other, and how to achieve communication also?

Answer (score 0):

To answer properly I'll stick with the technologies you've talked about.

I think you will need to apply the reactive pattern not only to the React part of your application, but also to the Angular one.

As you know Redux is a particular implementation of the Flux architecture and it makes you able to manage your app state through its api.
The cool part of it is that you can trigger a modification to the store from any part of the application and all of your components should be able to react to the store change.

Redux is agnostic respect to the frameworks in use, but there are some useful "bridge" libraries that could make your work much easier and luckily they have been developed for both React and Angular.
You can find React-redux bindings [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) (but I think you are already using it) and Angular2 bindings [here](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng2-redux).

So you should be able to update the store from any component, been it a React or an Angular one, and see the changes reflect to the application independently.